# Synchronous Transcription using Google Cloud Vision Optical Character Recognition (OCR)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, synchronous, google-cloud-vision

I am using the Google Cloud Vision OCR as an API for my web app. Users upload 5 files for processing but the endpoint processes them one by one.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/files/asyncBatchAnnotate

There's only documentation for asynchronous batch annotation. Any information on how I could make Google process multiple files at once without creating multiple accounts to process each document?

Comment: Here is the documentation for synchronous annotation: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/files/annotate

Comment: What do you mean by create multiple accounts for each document? Are you referring to service accounts or something else?